# how to restore the accidently overwritten .git directory

Tags: git

I accidently copy a directory to my working directory which also contains a .git directory and all my old version tracking history are gone. Anyway to restore the previous .git directory? Thanks a lot

Update: after I used data recovery tool to recover the .git directory, below is what I get:

```
$ git reset --hard
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt

$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
fatal: loose object 041ad083dc6c5b0c0cc6fa4a253c7b369f3dec9b (stored in .git/ob
ects/04/1ad083dc6c5b0c0cc6fa4a253c7b369f3dec9b) is corrupt
```

Comment: Do you have a copy of the repository anywhere else?

Comment: sorry, there is no other copy

Comment: If you didn't do a full directory replace, but rather a merge, your `.git` directory should contain objects (commit objects, file objects, tree objects) from both repos. Then I guess you'd just have to recreate the appropriate branches.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, unfortunately I did the whole directory replace and it messed everything

Comment: If you've overwritten the `.git` directory, your old repo is gone. Did you, by any chance, push it to some remote repository before that happened?

Comment: Sorry not yet, I do not have remote server. Actually I am trying to back tracking all my old non-tracked version. And do not have chance to backup or save it elsewhere.

Comment: now I use data recovery tool to recover the directory. Then the git says: bad signature, index file corrupt

Comment: Basically, the data of your .git repo is in .git/objects . Objects are named by their sha sum. If you did a recursive copy (`cp -R`), your objects from one repo should simple get added to object from the other repo. Since the files are named by their sha sum, if two files have the same name, their contents must be the same. Consequently, recursive copy on `.git/objects` should not result in data lost. What would get lost is your branch and log info, as there you could have collisions if you did a recursive copy. But that data is manually reconstructible.

Comment: I work on windows, and copy use the windows explorer. Now what I recovered using the recovery software:$ git reset --hard
error: bad signature
fatal: index file corrupt  $ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (invalid distance too far back)
fatal: loose object 041ad083dc6c5b0c0cc6fa4a253c7b369f3dec9b (stored in .git/ob
ects/04/1ad083dc6c5b0c0cc6fa4a253c7b369f3dec9b) is corrupt

Comment: First of all, backup your current repository by copying the whole folder. If you mess up with current recover process, just copy a new one and restart. And you shouldn't lost any real data except for refs like branches, tags, reflogs, etc. So don't worry. And porcelain commands are error prone at the moment, such as reset. I'm interested in the case, and I,ll have a try later.